# Using jQuery to check if 2 email address fields match

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use jQuery on a Wordpress form to check 2 email fields are the same before submitting the form. The code I have written doesn't seem to work. Any help would be highly appreciated:

The name of the form is `regform` and the fields are called `email` and `confirmemail`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#regform").submit(function(e) {
    removeFeedback();
   
    var errors = validateForm();
    if (errors == "") {
      return true;
    } else {
      provideFeedback(errors);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });

  function validateForm() {
    var errorFields = new Array();

    //check email addresses match
    if ($('#email').val() != $('#confirmemail').val()) {
      errorFields.push('confirmemail');
    }
    return errorFields;
  }

  function provideFeedback(incomingErrors) {
    for (var i = 0; i < incomingErrors.length; i++) {
      $("#" + incomingErrors[i]).
      addClass("errorClass");
      $("#" + incomingErrors[i] + "Error").
      removeClass("errorFeedback");
    }
    $("#errorDiv").html("Errors encountered");
  }

  function removeFeedback() {
    $("#errorDiv").html("");
    $('input').each(function() {
      $(this).addClass("errorFeedback");
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`validateForm` returns an array, so `errors == ""` will never be true. To check if the array contains any data you can use `length`:

```js
$("#regform").submit(function(e) {
  removeFeedback();

  var errors = validateForm();
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    provideFeedback(errors);
  }
});
```